# How to kill all processes started by script

Tags: shell-script, zsh, xorg

My `.xinit` script looks like this:

```
...
exec start_awesome.sh | logger -t awesome-session
```

All it does is call the base xinit and call my custom desktop init script.

Next, this is how `start_awesome.sh` looks like:

```
...
# Run stuff in the background
xsettingsd &
urxvt256cd -f
xscreensaver &
picom -b --experimental-backends
yandex-disk start
flatpak run org.keepassxc.KeePassXC &

awesome
pkill -P $$
```

That last `pkill` has the purpose of "gracefully exiting all stuff started by this script" because otherwise my X session won't end untill all of the previously forked process end.

The thing is, it doesn't work. The only way to kill my session along with all the forked processes is to call `kill 0` or `pkill -u 1000`, but that'd make Xorg complain about an unexpected signal. All I want is to kill all the stuff initiated by `start_awesome.sh` after awesome exits.

I created a test script that goes like this:

```
function child1 {
    echo "Child 1"
    sleep 3s
    echo "Child 1 end"
    exit 11
}

function parent {
    echo "Parent"
    sleep 1s
    echo "Parent end"
}

child1 &

parent
pkill -P ${$}
```

And that works as expected: It starts both child1 and parent and quits when parent ends. What's different from my `start_awesome.sh` script?

Comment: To make sure: does "it doesn't work" mean that `awesome` exits, but the processes started by `.xinitrc` aren't killed? Some or all of them? How is `awesome` exited (I'm not familiar with it)?

Comment: Correct -- all processes started before awesome by the script won't exit